# Extract data from javascript

Tags: json, stringify

have a java script element , which when printed, gives [object Object].

`console.log(data)`

When i tried to JSON.Stringify(data) -it gives a json value:

```
{"key":"value"}
```

How to extract the value from the above object ?

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` creates a JSON string representation of that JS object. If you want to use it as a JSON, you'd have to parse it again:

```
let data = '{"key": "value"}';
let dataJSON = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(dataJSON.key);
```

Outputs: `value`